# Unable to update ColdFusion after performing lock down steps

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am trying to install ColdFusion 11 (Standard) on a new Windows server (Windows Server 2012 R2). Installation was apparently successful, but when I go into the Administrator to install the latest update, I can't. When I click either the "Download" or the "Download and Install" button, nothing happens. I'm specifically hoping to install the latest cumulative update (5), but I tried the buttons for Update 4 also and they didn't work either. And from what I can find, Adobe no longer provides a manual way to download and install updates.

I tried launching the browser using "Run as administrator" and that didn't help. I've tried IE and Chrome. The rest of the Administrator seems to be working OK -- for example, I was able to update server settings.

In case it's helpful, here's the html that's generating the download buttons:

```
<input name="download" type="button" onclick="showDownloadProgressBar('pBarhf-11-0005','hf-11-0005','0',false,false)" value="Download" title="Download" class="buttn">
<input name="install" type="button" onclick="showDownloadInstallProgressBar('hf-11-0005')" value="Download and Install" title="Download and Install" class="buttn">
<input type="hidden" name="hfid" value="hf-11-0005">
```

I greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The manual updates are available, but let's try to figure the issue here. Have you applied the lockdown guide for ColdFusion? what is the "Default ScriptSrc Directory" set in CFAdmin (Server Settings)? Are you accessing the admin via the webserver or using the internal built-in server?

Comment: My guess is that your server does not have access to the Adobe website. Is it behind a firewall/proxy server?

Comment: The URL is http://www.adobe.com/go/coldfusion-updates/  Can you browse to that site from the server?

Comment: @Miguel-F, the server here is able to reach out to Adobe's website, as the user is able to see "Download" and "Download and Install" button.

Comment: @AnitKumar Really? I had a couple of CF11 servers here that are behind a proxy and cannot connect (without credentials) but still have those buttons.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you to all for the suggestions. The solution was hinted at by Anit. Here was my problem and solution.

I had tried to follow the lockdown guide. As such, I added request filtering to block access to /CFIDE/scripts. None of my applications use the affected tags, so I had not created a virtual directory and changed the default scripts directory in the Administrator. But this morning I realized that the Updates page in the Administrator uses CFFORM. So I created a virtual directory, updated the scripts directory in Administrator, and voila, problem solved.

If possible, I would suggest that the lockdown guide be updated (unless I missed this elsewhere in the guide). On page 36, it says, “If your web sites leverage certain tags or features you can change this URI to a non default URI outside of /CFIDE.” I think this should be changed because it’s not really optional. As best I can tell, the website under which the Administrator runs must have access to the scripts directory in order to perform updates. (The chart on page 28 does say the Administrator uses some of these tags, but, again, I think it would be helpful to point out that they’re required to perform updates.)

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings Rocky! It is unbelievable to me that Adobe has chosen to use `CFFORM` for the administrator update page. WOW!!!  Almost all of the ColdFusion vulnerabilities that come out are related to the directories under CFIDE. I never expose that directory to the outside world. Guess I will still be doing manual updates _sigh_

Comment: This post on the Adobe forums also mentions that the user had to re-allow the scripts folder access for the updater to work. https://forums.adobe.com/message/7253556#7253556

Comment: I'm still surprised there isn't a checkbox in admin to disable cfide virtual directory from being created, or why admin is also not reroutable to another url (eg: /myadmin/ ) also